# Cannot find Lando apache default config files

Tags: apache, lando

I'm using Lando to create a local development server for a Laravel project with the recipe below in `.lando.yml`

```
name: projectname
recipe: laravel
config:
  php: '7.3'
  composer_version: '2.0.7'
  via: apache:2.4
  webroot: .
  database: mysql:5.7
  cache: none
  xdebug: false
  config:
    server: lando/httpd.conf
```

I need to add a few lines to a custom `httpd.conf` so I specify a path `server: lando/httpd.conf`. However, I couldn't locate the current default `httpd.conf` in order to make a copy and use it as a custom file. The link provided on Lando official site doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking in the apache2 foler in the container?

```
$lando ssh
$cd /etc/apache2
```